# Class Not Found Exception while Exporting Eclipse Product in RCP

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I have added external `jar` in RCP application and also set class path in plugin.xml.

In workspace, it is working fine but while exporting Eclipse product, I am getting class not found exception.

My RCP application is standalone application.

Comment: Can you post exception too, it will more helpful!

Comment: What do you mean by 'external jar'? Accessing jars which are not in a plugin from an RCP is tricky.

Comment: Hi , actually i have added library to write on docx file in RCP application,when I am running on eclipse it is working fine but while exporting eclipse product I am facing Class not found exception.

Comment: All jars you use in an RCP should be part of a plugin. When you test from within Eclipse this requirement is not enforced.

Comment: Actually I have added external library in class path inside plugin.xml ...when I am running in eclipse it is working fine but when I am trying to export eclipse product and running then I am facing Class not found exception.

Comment: I think when I am running RCP application after exporting eclipse product,it is unable to find corresponding external library that's why it is throwing class not found exception...can any one give any suggestions to change in plugin.xml .